# How to show close button on top of stage webview in Flex stagewebview for facebook

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, stagewebview

I have Flex AIR app which uses StageWebView to load facebook login window. I want to add close button to stageWebView.
Is there any native function for stageWebView to add close button on top of StageWebView?
I have added close button, but it is not coming on top of StageWebView, because we cant add anything on top of StageWebView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add anything above StageWebView. The workaround is to position the viewPort say 50 pixels down from the top of the screen and add a close button to the Flash stage (or Starling stage if you're using Starling).

e.g. for iPad you could use something like:

```
_stageWebView.viewPort = new Rectangle(0, 50, 1024,718);
```